# How can I have onEdit trigger when specific cells are selected?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I can't seem to figure out how to get my script **to trigger only on the edit of specific cells** ***and on the current sheet***. I've tried just about everything and it just refuses to run the script at all if I change anything.

I've created new variables to try and select the specific cells, then trigger with an if statement all to no avail. The script below is the only current version I have working which triggers should I edit *anything anywhere.*

Please someone help me out, I've no idea what I've done wrong.

Edit: Updated the code I've been trying... Still not doing anything.

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var r  = sheet.getRange("D11");

if (r == 'Hide'){

  r.hideRows(11);

}}
```

Comment: Hi mate, yes I have and none of them worked... =[

Comment: How about this one [How to trigger a script when a new text value is added to specific column?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/121566/88163) ?

Comment: I did see that one, but it's actually not a column I'm trying to select, it's a specific cell e.g. C6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `getValue()` to `var r  = sheet.getRange("D11");`. The resulting code line is:

```
var r  = sheet.getRange("D11").getValue();
```

The above because getRange returns Range object which not return directly it's value/values.

Also replace `r.hideRows(11);` by `sheet.hideRows(11);`

For further details checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: Reloaded the document and it's working! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and its actually worked .

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var r  = sheet.getRange("L2").getValue();

if (r == 'ADD'){

// Add your code here
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

- try it like this

  ```
  function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Checklist" ) {        // sheet name
  var r = s.getActiveCell(); 
  if( r.getColumn() == 3 ) {                // column number
  ```

  your script here

  }}}

Comment: No luck. Same issue I was having where nothing happened at all. No errors, just nothing happens. Also, I've already got the column selected, but trying to select specific cells e.g. C6 so that it only triggers when those cells are edited.